# Does Flyway supports Netezza?

Tags: flyway

Does Flyway supports Netezza?

I need to migrate data from MySql to Netezza. So I need to connect netezza from Flyway. In google I found that in older versions netezza was not supported.
Is this possible in Flyway in the newer version?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Absent from the [list of supported databases](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/) in the [latest (4.0.3) release](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/releaseNotes).